# Number of edges in a planar graph where each face is incident to four edges.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Let $G$ be a planar graph with $n$ vertices and an embedding where each face is incident to exactly four edges. What is the number of edges in the graph?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know what Euler's formula is?

Comment: $$V-E+F=2$$$$n-E+\frac E2=2$$$$E=2n-4$$

Comment: @DonThousand how did you figure out $F = \frac{E}{2}$?

Comment: You can figure that much out :)

Comment: @DonThousand take any tree with $n=5$. Then $1=F\neq \frac 42$, unless we're working with the convention that edges that are bounded by one face are counted twice (once for each half-edge).

Comment: @DonThousand why wouldn't a tree with 4 edges satisfy the conditions? It is planar, with the only face incident to exactly four edges. The point is that $F=E/2$ is not clear-cut, unless certain conventions are assumed (and they're not always assumed).

Comment: @GoranMalic Fair enough. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not satisfied with the argument using $2F=E$ given in the comments (which is essentialy a counting argument, since each edge is bounded by exactly 2 faces, so the faces are overcounted by a factor of $2$, with one exceptional case when there is 4 edges incident to 1 face), you can instead look at the dual graph and use the handshaking lemma, because you know the degree of every vertex in the dual graph.

Let $V$, $E$ and $F$ be the number of vertices, edges and faces of $G$, respectively. Since $G$ is planar, it has a well defined dual graph $G^*$. The dual graph $G^*$ has $F$ vertices, $E$ edges and $V$ faces. From the Euler-Poincare formula we find that $G^*$ has
$$F=2-V+E$$
vertices. Because every face of $G$ is bounded by $4$ edges, every vertex of $G^*$ will be of degree $4$. Therefore, from the handshake lemma we obtain
$$2E=\sum_{v^* \text{ a vertex of }G^*}\deg v^*=4(2-V+E),$$
which after simplifying becomes
$$E=2V-4.$$

However, this formula does not account for trees with $4$ edges. So if $F=1$, there can be exactly $n=5$ vertices, or $F>1$ and $E=2V-4$.

It is often a convention to count the edges of a tree twice when talking about edge-face incidence (but in that case the language of half-edges is more appropriate). If you're working with that convention in place, then $E=2V-4$ covers trees as well, but each edge that is bounded by a single face must be counted twice.